# create authentication laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have these 2 tables with many to many relationship connected using a junction table. The idea is that I can get the user data to make the user an author in a journal data and it works so far.

User table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->integer('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->enum('level', ['admin', 'author']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Journal table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('journal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->text('abstract');
            $table->text('file');
            $table->integer('id_edition')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Junction table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('penulis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Create tabel penulis
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('id_journal')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            // Set PK
            $table->primary(['id_user', 'id_journal']);
            // Set FK penulis --- user
            $table->foreign('id_user')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
            // Set FK penulis --- journal
            $table->foreign('id_journal')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('journal')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Now I have this view that shows journals data along with the buttons to edit or delete it. What I want to make is that only the user that are entitled as the author of the journal that has the capacity to access these buttons. How do I make it ? below is the view code :

```
<tbody>
                                        <?php foreach ($journal_list as $journal): ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style=""><a href="{{ url('journal/' . $journal->id) }}">{{ $journal->title }}</a></td>

                                                @if (Auth::check())
                                                <td style="width: 130px; overflow: hidden;">
                                                    <div class="box-button">
                                                        {{ link_to('journal/' . $journal->id . '/edit?edition=' . $edition->id, 'Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="box-button">
                                                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['JournalController@destroy', $journal->id]]) !!}
                                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
                                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                @endif

                                            </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Sorry for my bad English and if my question is stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) and [Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization) facade.

1. [Generate a policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#generating-policies)
2. [Write a policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#writing-policies)

Like this:

```
public function edit-journal(User $user, Journal $journal)
{
     return $user->id === $journal->user_id;
}

public function delete-journal(User $user, Journal $journal)
{
   return $user->id === $journal->user_id;
}
```

3. You can now use the [Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-blade-templates) facade with blade

Like this:

```
@can('edit-journal', $journal)
    <div class="box-button">
       {{ link_to('journal/' . $journal->id . '/edit?edition=' . $edition->id, 'Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
    </div>
@endcan

@can('delete-journal', $journal)
    <div class="box-button">
         {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['JournalController@destroy', $journal->id]]) !!}
         {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
         {!! Form::close() !!}
     </div>
@endcan
```

4. You will have to [register a middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#registering-middleware) for your `edit` and `delete` route. Your routes should look like:

   ```
    //Routes
    Route::get('journal/' . {$journal_id} . '/edit',   ['as'=>'editJournal','middleware' => 'journal:edit', 'uses'=>'JournalController@edit'] 
    //You need to change your delete form so the action points to that route
    Route::delete('journal/' . {$journal_id},   ['as'=>'deleteJournal','middleware' => 'journal:delete', 'uses'=>'JournalController@destroy']
   ```

In your middleware, you should have something like:

```
    //Journal Middleware
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
         $parameters = $request->route()->parameters();
         $journal = Journal::findOrFail($parameters['journal_id']);
         if (Gate::allows($role.'-journal', $journal)) {
             return $next($request);
         }else{
             abort(403, "You do not have the permission to ".$role." this journal")
         }
     }
```

Comment: By using this, I have to create a new middleware ? If so, I tried this : public function handle($request, Closure $next, Journal $journal) {
        if (Gate::allows('editjournal', $journal)) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            abort(403, "You do not have the permission to update this journal");
        }
    }                      gave this error : Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuthor::handle() must be an instance of App\Journal, none given,

Comment: @AriandoMiller The middleware is what will prevent malicious user to access the ressource (ex: delete the journal) without having the appropriate level of access. You need to pass the `$journal_id` from your route to the middleware than retrieve the appropriate `Journal`. I edited the answer

Comment: It worked now, seems like the problem is I registered the middleware the wrong way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I;ve done in similar cases is to add a function inside the model that you want to check with all the logic. So for example in your case would be something like:

`/Model/Journal.php`

`public function canBeModifiedByUser($user_id){
   //Check all the things that you want
}`

Then in the view you can do something like:
`if($journal->canBeModifiedByUser($journal->user->id))`

Also I would suggest you to check some ACL packages, it might be an overkill for you atm but it might just be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using gates

in your auth service provider you can do

```
$gate->define('can-modifiy', function ($user) {
       // whatever code you want to determine if the user can eg
        return $user->hasRole('admin');
    });
```

then in your views you can use @can

```
 @can ('can-modify')
  <button>delete</button>
 @endcan
```

This can also be used in your controllers with

```
$this->authorize('can-modify');
```

or

```
Gate::allows('can-modify');
```

This is in the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#writing-gates